# 2051 Microcontroller Octave effect project

Tags: microcontroller

Is it possible to create a Guitar Effect on such microcontroller? I'm still new to these stuff and would like to know if it is. Basically what it will do would be reducing or halving the frequency input to create an octave down effect. But I'm not sure if the 2051 would be able to handle it.

Comment: Not sure why you have already decided on a microcontroller even before you have any idea of what problems you have to solve first.

Comment: Sadly, we have been restricted on using the 2051 MCU only.

Comment: There may be other effects you can implement, they will be crude but perhaps interesting. This website is not a good place to discuss that, however.

Comment: Answer is no. Clearly, this MCU is not powerful enough for this kind of advanced effects. You'd need a DSP.

Comment: Ask your teacher how often these chips have been used in former classes. They may have already reached their 1000 flash/erase cycles in 20+ years.

Comment: @TurboJ Well, we will be buying a new chip so that's not a problem.

Comment: @pipe Can you point me to where I can discuss that? Please.  I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### No.

You need three components, and if I guess correctly, your microcontroller has neither.

1. An A/D-converter to sample the input signal.
2. Enough horsepower to perform the necessary calculations.
3. A D/A converter to output the data as audio.

Number 1 and 3 can be solved by adding external components. Number 2 can not.

Comment: What do you mean by horsepower? I'm sorry if this is a dumb question. We were only taught on mostly the programming on the microcontroller. What if I change it to 4051? We have been given the permission to use that if needed.

Comment: @WarrenGojar I don't know what a "4051" is. By _horsepower_ I mean that it can not calculate fast enough, and it has too little memory.

Comment: It's somehow an upgraded version of 2051. It adds 2k bytes of memory I think. How should I determine the calculation speed? Is it the maximum operating freq.? Thank you very much for all the answers. Sorry for being too ignorant.